# Best design for handling complete history in a DBMS

Tags: sql, database-design

I am developing a website with a DBMS with several entities and relationships. I want users of the website to be able to view a complete history of what has been changed in certain entites, e.g. when, by whom and what a field has been changed to.

So far I have considered to use a linked list approach where you simply persist rather than update an entity, and keep an ID to the previous entity. However, since relationships can change, I will not know how the linked entity was at the time of the previous update. **What I mean by relationships can change:** Say I have a Person entity which has a connection to another Person entity. If I only hold on to the ID of the other Person, I cannot know if the other Persons fields have been updated, e.g. if the other Person has for example changed its name field. Please see below for further explenation.

Another approache might be to sequentially save every change to the database, and simply revert back to a given change, e.g. save every sql query ever made.

Does anyone know a proper way to handle this? Thanks in advance.

**Update**

Lets say I have an entity which is called Person (see below). The Person can have many parents and children. Lets also say a user can update values in a existing Person. Whenever a user for example updates the name field, I want to save this change, so other users can revert the change, if desired. As mentioned, if I only hold on to the ID of the parent, I cannot know wether the Person with that ID has changed or not. For example if the parents name was updated.

```
Person {
    int id;
    String name; 
    List<Person> parents;
    List<Person> children;
}
```

In conclusion: I need to display a list of this Person entity for whenever it has been updated. In this list I need to see what the Persons fields did contain, but also how its parents and children looked at the time of the given change.

Comment: Your question is way too broad and your details are scarce.

Comment: @PM77-1 Could you please elaborate? What I am asking is how I should approach saving each change made in a database so it can retrieved for the user. It is important that all entities connected to the reverted entity are displayed in the state they were when the change was executed.

Comment: Complete history of **what**? Do you really need it for ***every*** field?  What do you mean by *relationships can change*?

Comment: Complete history of when entities are changed/updated, e.g. if a field containing for example a name is updated from "a" to "b". I guess it would be more correct to say I need to know the new state of the entity, in other words: which fields where changed and which value they now contain. What I mean by relationships can change: Say I have a Person entity which has a connection to another Person entity. If I only hold on to the ID of the other Person, I cannot know if the other Persons fields have been updated, e.g. if the other Person has change its name field. I hope this was a bit clearer.

Comment: Put your clarifications in your question.  Provide reasonable sample data, value change scenarios and desired output to your users.

Comment: You need 2 tables here: Person and Relationship.  This way you can have many-to-many relationship for self-join.

Comment: That is correct, but the relationship is not the problem, I have already two tables. The problem is how to save the state of the entity and other entites connected by relationships at a given time. The question contain only a small example, but if I include other entites as well, such as images or posts things get complicated.

Comment: You need to **normalize** your data. This way every individual update will be limited to a single record in some table. If you need to preserve complete history then you will need historic version of each table where every record update will be stored with its values, time stamp and user ID.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are implying I should use the approach where an entity is persisted for each update, while maintaining an ID to the previous entity, but also logging a timestamp. Based on this timestamp I can compare the different tables and revert properly. This can absolutely work, I will check it out! Thanks.

Comment: Your time stamp is enough. No need to *link* individual updates for the same table.

Comment: It sounds to me like what you need is a temporal database which records the time periods when data is valid, etc.  You might even need a bitemporal database.  I've not read all the details in your question, but the topic is complex.  You could look up R T Snodgrass ([publications](https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/~rts/publications.html)) and chase links.  His 'Developing Time-Oriented Database Applications in SQL' book is interesting but tough going.  If you understand it, it may help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to create some sort of audit history whenever a change is made to a table and allow retrieval of the changes made?

> Whenever a user for example updates the name field, I want to save this change, so other users can revert the change, if desired

Consider your entity Person which would have a database table like:

```
Person
id INT
name NVARCHAR(20)
parentId INT
```

to keep the change history, you can have a Person Change History table in your database:

```
PersonCH
RevisionCount INT
id INT
name NVARCHAR 
parentId INT
ChangeDateTime DATETIME
ChangedByUserID INT
```

To explain how this would work, lets work through your example:

Lets add a person called John:

```
INSERT INTO Person VALUES (100,'John',99);
```

At the same time, we should also add a record to our history table:

```
INSERT INTO PersonCH (1,100,'John',99,GETDATE(),123);
```

and if we change John's name we again add a new record to the history table:

```
UPDATE Person SET name = 'Jim' WHERE id = 100;
INSERT INTO PersonCH (2,100,'Jim',99,GETDATE(),123);
```

In reality, the `INSERT` statement above would be in an `AFTER INSERT` and / or `AFTER UPDATE` trigger so we don't need to rely on always specifying it in our application.

Therefore our history table now has an audit trail of this Person's changes which we can see using

```
SELECT * FROM PersonCH WHERE id = 100 ORDER BY RevisionCount DESC;
```

Comment: I think this is a good solution as well. It would eliminate redundant entities, for example for searching the Person entities. Thanks!